# Fine-grained authorization with public client using keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, keycloak, openid-connect

From my understanding, a client (in our case SPA) will exchange an `authorization_code` for an `access_token` with the authorization server (keycloak).

This `access token` can then be sent to the Resource Server (in our case, Spring server), which then controls and grant access to the resources available.

A confidential client can customize these authorization to a deep level (using permissions, scope and policies). Whereas a public client only could use client scope. (Is there any difference between scope and client scope ?)

The difference between a `public` and a `confidential` client is that the `public` client can't be trusted to hold credentials. (Such as a client secret).

It still doesn't stop you from using any role mapping (afaik coarse-grained authz) whatsoever, therefore :

- How come only coarse-grained authorization is available for a public client ?
- How should I workaround that ? Configure my resource reserver as a keycloak client & somehow share the JWT securely ? While mapping the public's app roles to the resource server ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just define how Spring authorities should be mapped from JWT claims or introspected attributes.

In the following, I map authorities from Keycloak "roles" from "realm" and two different clients (one confidential and one public, but this makes absolutely no difference). Just open one of your JWT access-token in a tool like https://jwt.io or call introspection endpoint with a valid access-token to see attributes (and figure out where are roles, permissions, groups or whatever should be mapped to Spring authorities).

#### JWT decoder

You can configure a `Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>`:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter) {
    http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);
}

public interface Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> {
}

public interface Jwt2AuthenticationConverter extends Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
public Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter() {
    return jwt -> {
        final var realmAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("realm_access", Map.of());
        final var realmRoles = (Collection<String>) realmAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());

        final var resourceAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("resource_access", Map.of());
        // We assume here you have "spring-addons-confidential" and
        // "spring-addons-public" clients configured with "client roles" mapper in
        // Keycloak
        final var confidentialClientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess
                .getOrDefault("spring-addons-confidential", Map.of());
        final var confidentialClientRoles = (Collection<String>) confidentialClientAccess.getOrDefault("roles",
                List.of());
        final var publicClientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.getOrDefault("spring-addons-public",
                Map.of());
        final var publicClientRoles = (Collection<String>) publicClientAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());

        return Stream
                .concat(realmRoles.stream(),
                        Stream.concat(confidentialClientRoles.stream(), publicClientRoles.stream()))
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList();
    };
}

@Bean
public Jwt2AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter(Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesConverter) {
    return jwt -> new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt));
}
```

#### Token introspection

Since spring-security 5.8, you can define an authentication converter  for access-token introspection too:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, OpaqueTokenAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter) {
    http.oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken().authenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);
}

@Bean
OpaqueTokenAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter(
        Converter<Map<String, Object>, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesConverter) {
    return (String introspectedToken,
            OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal authenticatedPrincipal) -> new BearerTokenAuthentication(
                    authenticatedPrincipal,
                    new OAuth2AccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER, introspectedToken,
                            authenticatedPrincipal.getAttribute(OAuth2TokenIntrospectionClaimNames.IAT),
                            authenticatedPrincipal.getAttribute(OAuth2TokenIntrospectionClaimNames.EXP)),
                    authoritiesConverter.convert(authenticatedPrincipal.getAttributes()));
}

public interface Attributes2AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Map<String, Object>, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> { }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
public Attributes2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter() {
    return attributes -> {
        final var realmAccess = (Map<String, Object>) attributes.getOrDefault("realm_access", Map.of());
        final var realmRoles = (Collection<String>) realmAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());

        final var resourceAccess = (Map<String, Object>) attributes.getOrDefault("resource_access", Map.of());
        // We assume here you have "spring-addons-confidential" and
        // "spring-addons-public" clients configured with "client roles" mapper in
        // Keycloak
        final var confidentialClientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess
                .getOrDefault("spring-addons-confidential", Map.of());
        final var confidentialClientRoles = (Collection<String>) confidentialClientAccess.getOrDefault("roles",
                List.of());
        final var publicClientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.getOrDefault("spring-addons-public",
                Map.of());
        final var publicClientRoles = (Collection<String>) publicClientAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());

        return Stream
                .concat(realmRoles.stream(),
                        Stream.concat(confidentialClientRoles.stream(), publicClientRoles.stream()))
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList();
    };
}
```

#### Make things simple

I maintain [spring-boot starters](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) which are thin wrappers arround `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`. It allows to configure most of resource-servers security from properties file: authorities mapping (with hand on prefix and case), off course, but also other usefull stuff like CORS, CSRF, public routes and session-management:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@EnableMethodSecurity
public static class WebSecurityConfig { }
```

```
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://localhost:8443/realms/master
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,ressource_access.some-client.roles

com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/some-api
```

And as a bonus, it comes with tools to ease your access-control unit & integration tests:

```java
@Test
@WithMockJwtAuth(authorities = "ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL", claims = @OpenIdClaims(sub = "Ch4mpy"))
void greetMockCh4mpy() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/greet")).andExpect(content().string("Hello Ch4mpy! You are granted with [ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL]."));
}
```

Refer to [tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) and [samples](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples) for more details and declinations for

- servlet or reactive apps
- JWT decoding or token introspection
- Spring default or custom Authentication implementations

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer.  


This is a very detailled answer, however I'm not there yet.   

I am still trying to figure out why having a public client prevents me from using fine-grained authorization.

Then, all though I configure my resource server as a Keycloak Client, I will end up with a flooded channel between the Resource Server and Keycloak to check every authorizations mapped.

Plus considering I'll need to use token exchange which is a technology preview to exchange my JWT from the public client to private client.

Comment: The client being public or private does not change anything. Authorization-server puts security information as claims in tokens, and other actors (clients and resource-servers) read it from there. Please follow advices, open an access-token granted to your "public" client, see what is available there and follow the tutorials linked to learn how to use this data in spring-security.